# Alternatives to llama_index's download_loader for initializing BotoMinioReader

Tags: python, nlp, loader, minio, llama-index

I am using llama_index package and I found this plugin that supposely allows to access MinIo files thorugh boto3 [here](https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/tree/main/llama-index-integrations/readers/llama-index-readers-minio/llama_index) but I can't get it to work.

```
/opt/project/src/core/loader/loader.py:3: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function (or staticmethod) download_loader. (`download_loader()` is deprecated. Please install tool using pip install directly instead.)
  MinioReader = download_loader("BotoMinioReader")
```

I know they have changed a lot of things recently but I don't see any similar alternatives online. Only a few of different APIs to deal with MinIO.

I tried running the example they give with the new location of the package.

```
import llama_index.core.download_loader

MinioReader = download_loader("BotoMinioReader")
loader = MinioReader(
    bucket="documents",
    aws_access_id="<minio_access_key>",
    aws_access_secret="<minio_secret_key>",
    s3_endpoint_url="localhost:9000",
)
documents = loader.load_data()
```

I have almost zero experience with the library so any help is welcomed.